# Calculating coordinates of a point

Tags: 2d, mathematics, vector

I struggle to find coordinates of point B in the picture below. I know the positions of `A` and `C`, the length of arm `c` and angle `beta`

[image]

I need it to make a gun next to the player point to the direction of a cursor. And the gun will rotate with the player. I think there must be a simple way to do it, but I'm missing it somehow. Could you point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If beta is 90°:

The `CAB` angle is `angle = acos(c / AC)`, the B point is

```
A + (AC.x * cos(angle) - AC.y * sin(angle), AC.x * sin(angle) + AC.y * cos(angle)) / |AC| * c
```

Where `|a|` is the length of the a vector

If beta isn't 90°:

the law of sines (`a / sin(A) = b / sin(B) = c / sin(C)`) says, that

```
|AC| / sin(beta) = c / sin(gamma)
```

We can reorder this to get gamma:

```
gamma = asin(c / |AC| * sin(beta)
```

Then use the rotation above:

```
B = C + (CA.x * cos(gamma) - CA.y * sin(gamma), CA.x * sin(gamma) + CA.y * sin(gamma)) / |AC| * sqrt(|AC|^2 - c^2)
```

Comment: It's correct only if beta = 90°, right? What if beta is some other angle?

Comment: @chriemmy let me add that

Comment: @chriemmy Here you go